# How to revert N choose 2 combinations?

Tags: python

I have a set of pairs that can contain the result of mutliple "N choose 2" combinations:

```py
inputs = {
    ('id1', 'id2'), ('id1', 'id3'), ('id1', 'id4'),
    ('id2', 'id3'), ('id2', 'id4'),
    ('id3', 'id4'), ('id3', 'id5'),
    ('id4', 'id5'),
    ('id5', 'id6'),
}
```

And I would like to reverse those combinations, like this:

```py
recombinations = [
    ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'),
    ('id3', 'id4', 'id5'),
    ('id5', 'id6'),
]
```

I managed to do it using brute-force:

```py
ids = list(sorted( {i for i in itertools.chain(*inputs)} ))

excludes = set()
recombinations = {tuple(i) for i in map(sorted, inputs)}

for i in range(3, len(ids)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(ids, i):
        for j in range(i-1, len(subset)):
            combs = set(itertools.combinations(subset, j))
            if all(tup in recombinations for tup in combs):
                recombinations.add(subset)
                excludes = excludes.union(combs)

for tup in excludes:
    recombinations.remove(tup)

print(recombinations)
```

```py
{('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'), ('id3', 'id4', 'id5'), ('id5', 'id6')}
```

Is there a smarter way to do it? Or some optimizations that I can add to the code?

Comment: what do you mean by "of order 2" ?  Why are some of your recombinations of size 4, 3, and 2?

Comment: @selbie Thank you for the comment. I might be wrong (because I didn't study math in english) but the combination of order 2 of `(1,2,3)` are `(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)`. Is that right?

Comment: In your example in the comment, the sizes remain 2, but in the example in the question the sizes are 4,3,2. Why?  Maybe I'm just asking to elaborate " reverse-combinations of order 2"

Comment: He's saying that his pairs are composed of `(1, 2, 3, 4) choose 2`, `(3, 4, 5) choose 2`, and `(5, 6) choose 2`.

Comment: Oh.... the `recombinations` is the actual input. and the variable declared `input` is what the OP wants to generate?  (i.e. `recombinations` is input and `input` is the output).  Is that correct?

Comment: Or is the problem saying for every 4 pairs in `input`, generate the unique set and add to `recombinations` ?

Comment: @selbie, you got the reverse of the actual problem on your first attempt.

Comment: There is always the trivial recombination of simply saying it's each pair choose 2, but the more interesting question is how to get the sparsest answer.

Comment: I think there's confusion how these elements should be recombined. Could you give a few very clear examples of how that happens.

Comment: If I'm understanding this right, it sounds like you want to find all subsets `S` of the set of underlying combination elements, such that every pair of elements of `S` occurs in `input`, and no elements can be added to `S` and still keep this property. Is that correct? If so, this is the problem of finding all maximal cliques in a graph, and you should just [throw NetworkX at the problem](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html).

Comment: So its N choose 2 for each tuple of items in the recombinations list? That's not what I thought was happening, but I get it now.

Comment: I think you'll need to brute-force it only, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103377/how-to-reverse-the-n-choose-k-formula) for a mathematical derivation and a python implementation of the general formula

Comment: Your process of N choose 2 creates a one to many mapping of inputs to outputs. To reverse this there is no way to match the outputs to exactly where they came from unless you have the recombinations list but if you have that, then you already have the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `networkx` library, this is quite simple, since it has a function that does exactly what you're asking for: finding all maximal cliques in a graph.

Here:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

pairs_of_connected_nodes = [
    ('id1', 'id2'), ('id1', 'id3'), ('id1', 'id4'),
    ('id2', 'id3'), ('id2', 'id4'),
    ('id3', 'id4'), ('id3', 'id5'),
    ('id4', 'id5'),
    ('id5', 'id6')
]

G.add_edges_from(pairs_of_connected_nodes)

maximal_cliques = list(nx.find_cliques(G))

for clique in maximal_cliques:
    print(clique)
```

Output:

```
['id3', 'id4', 'id2', 'id1']
['id3', 'id4', 'id5']
['id6', 'id5']
```

Of course if your assignment is to implement the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm yourself, you'd have to code it up - but then asking on StackOverflow kind of defeats the purpose, unless you have a specific problem with your solution that you need help with?

If you're just asking for a review of your code, ask on Code Review Stack Exchange, but expect to get told to use `networkx` as well.

Comment: That's definitely simpler. Thank you